# adding multiple custom columns to users.php

Tags: customization, actions

I'm trying to add two columns to the users.php file. I'm not sure how to add both $total_time_display and $logged_in_amount_display. How could I return both values?

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'freeman_add_user_minutes_column');
function freeman_add_user_minutes_column($columns) {
    $columns['total_time'] = 'Total Minutes';
    $columns['logged_in_amount'] = 'Number of Logins';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content', 10, 3);
function freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'total_time' == $column_name )
        $total_time_display = ($user->total_time);
        return $total_time_display;
    if ( 'logged_in_amount' == $column_name )
        $logged_in_amount_display = ($user->logged_in_amount);
        return $logged_in_amount_display;
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: You are not defining the `total_time` or the `logged_in_amount`.  Neither of these are valid objects of the `get_userdata()` method.  You will need to create the function for each of the values you are trying to ascertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help buys but I ended up figuring it out. Just echoing the code did not give me the results I wanted but returning it did.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'freeman_add_user_minutes_column');
function freeman_add_user_minutes_column($columns) {
    $columns['total_time'] = 'Total Minutes';
    $columns['logged_in_amount'] = 'Number of Logins';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content', 10, 3);
function freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'total_time' == $column_name )
        $output .= ($user->total_time);
    if ( 'logged_in_amount' == $column_name )
        $output .= ($user->logged_in_amount);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct to use  `echo` not `return`. This is action, not the filter. And you can delete `return $value;` from your callback.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing at what your meta fields are calling, implementing Oleg's suggestions would mean updating your `freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content()` function like so:

```
add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content', 10, 3);
function freeman_show_user_minutes_column_content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'total_time' == $column_name )
        echo get_user_meta( $user_id, 'total_time', true );
    if ( 'logged_in_amount' == $column_name )
        echo get_user_meta( $user_id, 'logged_in_amount' );
}
```

Your custom meta isn't part of the `$user` object, so instead, you have to use [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).